# How to access nested arrays in objects from a particular record?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is the sample JSON object.
What is the way to access the second record's list array?

```
var myPlants = [
  { 
    type: "flowers",
    list: [
      "rose",
      "tulip",
      "dandelion"
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "trees",
    list: [
      "fir",
      "pine",
      "birch"
    ]
  }  
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it like this :

```
myPlants[1].list
```